# Weight Loss without the gym

Tags: weight-loss

I need to reduce my belly fat but due to certain unavoidable reasons I do not have access to a gym. What should I do? Where should I start?

Answer (score -1):

The best way for you is to do the "burpees" exercise
When you do this just make sure that you do this with a smaller rest time between each set (A set is how many you're able to do continuously)

- 5 sets of [burpees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burpee_(exercise)) every day, evening and morning, will do the job
- Don't do abs exercises for now
- After burpees do side bends
- And then followed by plank exercise.

This will be sufficient.